# Get difference between model versions after save

Tags: product, event-observer, magento-1.9, model

Is there any possibility to get attribute data difference between model versions? I create observer for `catalog_product_save_after` action, and now i want to make some changes only if attribute `product_versions` has changed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newValue = $product->getData('product_versions');
$oldValue = $product->getOrigData('product_versions');
```

Now check if the 2 values are different. If they are, do your magic.

Comment: Something similar here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182009/get-product-changes

Comment: @Marius, What if I don't have any specific attribute to compare? I need to compare if any data has been changed or not? As I see it wont be better way to compare both giant arrays `$product->getData()` and `$product->getOrigData()`. Please can you suggest any different way?